# Postfix mail to yahoo.com servers bounce with deferred status 4.4.1

Tags: postfix

I've been seeking a resolution to this problem for a bit now. We started noticing yahoo.com emails bouncing back with a deferred status last week. Here's a sample of one of the bounced messages.

```
    3B8C812412C: to=<[redacted]@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=90, delays=0.05/0.02/90/0,   dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to yahoo.com[206.190.36.45]:25: Connection timed out)
```

We're using a virtualmin setup on Ubuntu 12.04. We have no entries in dnsbl or through the mxtoolbox blacklist lookup. I've contacted the Yahoo postmaster through the bulk mail form, but that was 3 days ago and nothing has changed. All messages still bounce, but only through Yahoo.

Anyone have suggestions or help they can provide on this frustrating problem?

Comment: Contact your ISP.

Comment: The [redacted] have you changed for us here? Or is that the mail address you're sending to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That IP address [206.190.36.45] doesn't appear in any of the yahoo.com MX records. It *does* however appear in the default A records for the domain.

I would suggest that you undo whatever misconfiguration you've made because mail does not work like this.

Comment: This led me to look at how the server was handling DNS. My partner had turned off Bind recently and made direct changes to the /etc/resolv.conf file. This caused the problems that since became resolved after turning Bind back on and reverting to the correct way of handling the resolv.conf file. Thanks for leading me to the source with the insight you provided.